Measure of the derivatives of a probability density function with support on $\mathbb{R}$
Let $f$ be a probability density with support on $\mathbb{R}$ ($\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| = 1$), moreover $f$ is absolutely continuous on every bounded interval and has derivatives almost everywhere $f'$ and $f''$. Is true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f' = 0 $ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'' = 0 $?
My attempt
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f' = 0 $ is true using absolute continuity, ideed we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f' = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{(-\infty, x]} f'$=$f(\infty)-f(-\infty)$=0-0=0 because the probability density tails must go to 0.
Intiutively, I think it should be true for every further derivatives but I don't see an easy way to prove it without absolute continuity / the fundamental theorem of calculus.
EDIT: In alternative, which additional hypotesys we need on $f'$ or $f''$?

Why is $f(\infty)=0$?

Because f is a probability density on R, to sum up to 1 its tails mist go to 0 on both the directions or its integral will not be bounded.

$\int_x^{\infty} f(t)dt \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for any density function $f$ but it is not true in general that $f(\infty)=0$.

If $f$ has derivatives of all orders at very point and if all the derivatives are integrable, then their integrals are all $0$.
